# compare two Integer objects with == in java

Tags: java

```
public class Problem {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Integer a=200;
        Integer b=200;
        Integer c=20;
        Integer d=20;

        System.out.println(a==b);
        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
        System.out.println(c==d);
        System.out.println(c.equals(d));
    }
}
```

output

```
false
true
true
true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer class keeps a local cache between `-128 to 127` and returns the same object. So,

```
    Integer a=200; --> Internally converted to Integer.valueOf(200);
    Integer b=200; // not same as a
    Integer c=20;
    Integer d=20; // same as c

    Integer c=new Integer(20);
    Integer d=new Integer(20);
    c==d --> returns false; because you are comparing references.
```

Comment: is it so.did not know about a local cache. seems an awesome answer

Comment: @vikeng21 - Yep. That's the case. check [oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf)

Answer (score 1):

Compare objects only using equals except you really want to make sure both are the same objects not just equal.
In case of the boxed primitives I believe that I have Seen once that some basic numbers are cached so that in these cases Java will return one and the same object. I can't verify this right now but this would explain the behavior you are facing.